# Can I better predict a data point's class based on the other data points in the same observation?

Tags: bayesian, classification, predictive-models

I have a set of classes lets call them class X, Y and Z.
Per observation, I observe some data points that I can classify into said classes. For example:

1. YYY
2. XXX
3. XXXZY
4. YZ

Where might I look for an analysis that addresses the question- Can I better predict a data point's class based on the other data points in the same observation?

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: each sample is a sequence of data points, where each single data point needs to be classified to one of several classes based on the features of this individual data point; and additionally, (you suspect) there are sequential dependencies between data points that may provide more information during the classification and you want to use that. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: In effect yes. Although I wouldn't use the word sequential. I suspect that observing several data points with class X would provide more information for classifying an additional data point within the same observation

Comment: Because the order between those data points doesn't matter?

Comment: The order doesn't matter correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description and additional info in the comments, I would suggest two possible approaches:

- [Conditional random field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field), which is a structured prediction model that takes into account dependencies between predictions. The sequential case admits an efficient solution, however here since all data points depend on each other some adaptation and heuristics would be required (I think).
- Explore existing work on [deep learning on graphs](https://www.dgl.ai/), as this is a problem with a simple complete graph.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions!